# Receiver triggers a few seconds after initial run

Tags: android, android-service

I have this `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`

```
public class UpdateAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
        NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetInfo != null && activeNetInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            Intent service = new Intent(context, UpdateSchedulingService.class);
            startWakefulService(context, service);
        }
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateAlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        final Random r = new Random();
        final int hour = r.nextInt(24-9) + 9;
        final int minute = r.nextInt(60-1) + 1;
        final int second = r.nextInt(60-1) + 1;
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        //calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);

        Toast.makeText(context,"Freq set to: "+Integer.toString(hour)+":"+Integer.toString(minute)+":"+Integer.toString(second),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY, alarmIntent);

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, UpdateBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

When I run the app for the first time I'm calling the `setAlarm()` method and activate the alarm manager by default. But after the initial app run the receivers `onReceive` is triggered after a few seconds even though the initial time was set to another period of the day.I can't understand why its being triggered and how to avoid it.

Comment: If your alarm fires pretty much right after you set it, then you've given it a date/time in the past. You need to account for the possibility that the random time you're generating has already passed today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your alarm in the past, it will trigger immediately.

You use

```
final Random r = new Random();
final int hour = r.nextInt(24-9) + 9;
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
```

This will set the calendar to the current time, and if

1. the hour is before now, it will be the same day some time *ago* triggering immediately, or
2. the hour is after now, it will trigger on the same day, to the specified time

You should `add` your time to the calendar, and not set it yourself, or imrpove your calculatioins, to remove this error.